# Why did Sally Beth Roe have that particular last name?

Tags: name-significance, piercing-the-darkness, frank-peretti

"Jane Roe" a common name for an anonymous or unknown individual (similar to "John Doe" for men) - notably, for example, in the case *Roe v. Wade*. That being said, why was Sally Beth Roe's last name "Roe"? What is the significance of this in terms of the storyline?